# Multiple handsontable on same page

Tags: jquery, handsontable

I am trying to add two handsontable to the same page in my project but it doesnt work.

```
$(function () {

    $table1= $("#table1");
    $table2= $("#table2");

    var data1 = [
          ["", "", "", ""]
    ];

    $table1.handsontable({
        data: data1,
        minSpareRows: 1,
        colHeaders: ["#", "1", "2", "3"]
    });

    var data2= [
        ["", "", ""]
    ];

    $table2.handsontable({
        data: data2,
        minSpareRows: 1,
        colHeaders: ["#", "1", "2"]
    });
})
```

But this doesnt work. Only the first table gets displayed. If I comment out the first one then the second one gets displayed. I see on the project samples that there are indeed multiple tables on the same page working correctly. So what am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I am not sure why it works this way but separating the calls to handsontable into two script tags, one for each table, solves the problem.

Comment: Just FYI for anyone who comes along later, the code above worked fine for me without being split into two script tags.  Not sure if it was a browser or handsontable version difference or what, but the above code worked for me without alteration.